# MVC 5 Ajax File Upload Not Deserializing in Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

For some reason I'm having an issue deserializing the data being sent using the multipart/form-data type.  This is an MVC 5 project and data is not being mapped into the controller method.  The strange part is that in Fiddler all the data appears valid without a problem.  However, when debugging I can clearly see that the parameters are all null.

This is a form that sends one text field (hidden) and up to two files to the controller.  Below is the signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFile(string id, FormCollection form, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
```

The implementation of the method I think is irrelevant for this question since the issue is that the parameters are not being populated.

Without posting the mess that is the actual file contents here's the redacted version of the Fiddler output:

```
POST http://localhost:52876/Projects/UploadFile/5550cdc52300560f6c7b36eb HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:52876
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 90889
Authorization: Negotiate oXcwdaADCgEBoloEWE5UTE1TU1AAAwAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAAAFgAAAAAAAAAWAAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAAAFgAAAAAAAAAWAAAABXCiOIGAbEdAAAADwAbnJriMKEzkS3OifgoahejEgQQAQAAAPUXp1AtIpqEAAAAAA==
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:52876
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:52876/Projects/ProjectSetupForm/5550cdc52300560f6c7b36eb
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: donotshowgettingstarted=%7B%22state%22%3Atrue%7D; __RequestVerificationToken=UnL5s7w5OYKgywE5L8jqwbH8PulgF0BG0Ne_qZV5QMOj7pWdXw6qzN1pRYqc4rwKYiWveltrBs1SmJe2o7ndXufkOJFrC1wHOoK2zAXdnQw1

------WebKitFormBoundaryB3sb0uQDOIiNQXCD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__RequestVerificationToken"

  f25ipWgwweX4S9Y6aEnQdxGCsvr7D3RznTui8_b5paCT1uTV8UNG0d6zJDXKUWYPHISOKmgD24KH206x_PGQ3KpXlG9YgOL-qqJ8v7DPETVfGk2PvsFm2aKuAS3xAYZI0
------WebKitFormBoundaryB3sb0uQDOIiNQXCD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="MyIcon.bmp"
Content-Type: image/bmp

[REDACTED FILE CONTENTS]

------WebKitFormBoundaryB3sb0uQDOIiNQXCD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryB3sb0uQDOIiNQXCD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

output
------WebKitFormBoundaryB3sb0uQDOIiNQXCD--
```

As you can see in the above debugging data only one file is being sent and the file field is blank.  I've tested and I receive the same results when both are populated.

Here's the JavaScript method that's being used to capture the onSubmit of the form:

```
$('#attachment-upload form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#attachment-upload').removeClass('fade').modal('hide');
    $('#attachment-progress').modal('show').addClass('fade');

    $.ajax({
        xhr: function () {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
                    $('#attachment-progress div.modal-body .progress-bar').width(percent);
                    $('#attachment-progress div.modal-body .progress-bar').attr('aria-valuenow', percent);
                    $('#attachment-progress div.modal-body .progress-bar span').html(percent);
                }
            }, false);

            return xhr;
        },

        url: this.action,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "multipart/form-data",
        processData: false,
        data: new FormData(this),
        success: function (data) {
            //my success function here
        },
        error: function (jqxhr, status, error) {
            $('#upload-progress-section').addClass('hidden');
            $('#upload-complete-section').removeClass('hidden');

            $('#attachment-progress div.modal-header h1').html("Upload Error");
            $('#upload-complete-section p').html("Upload has failed: " + status + " - " + error);
            $('#attachment-progress div.modal-footer button').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Based on what I'm seeing in Fiddler it feel like there is most likely something wrong with the method signature in the controller, which is causing the binding to the parameters to fail.  I'm surprised though that the FormCollection parameter is null too.

Are there known issues with using multipart/form-data upload files via ajax, or is it something that I'm doing incorrectly here?

Comment: For starters your `Content-Type` request header seems wrong. According to the [`specification`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) it should look like this: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=WebKitFormBoundaryB3sb0uQDOIiNQXCD`. Yours seem to be missing the `boundary` part.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks so much!  That wasn't exactly the fix, but it pointed me in the right direction!  The missing boundary was the problem...content-type should have been set to `false`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DarinDimitrov for the heads up the issue was that the multipart/form-data content type requires a defined boundary.

By setting the `$.ajax` option `contentType: false` instead of explicitly defining it as multipart-form/data, the ajax method was able to automatically insert the proper boundary definition and the controller was then able to deserialize the data properly.